# Angular JS - The directive is accessible between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am new to Angular and just wondering how come my directive is accessible between controller as I only register it into sub controller, not main app controller. Below is my code.

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module('adminPage', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'login', 'registerEmployee', 'listEmployee'])
    .controller('adminPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$location' , funcAdminPageCtrl]);
angular.module('login',[]);
angular.module('registerEmployee', []);
angular.module('listEmployee', []);
```

So as stated, I have `adminPage` acts as a main controller and others as sub controllers.

**registerEmployeeController.js**

```
angular.module('registerEmployee')
    .controller('registerEmployeeCtrl', ['$scope', funcRegisterEmployeeCtrl
    ])
    .directive("compareTo", ['$timeout', funcCompareTo]);
```

As seen above, I register the `compareTo` directive to `registerEmployee` sub controller.

I would like to use the same directive in `listEmployeeController.js`'s `ModalInstanceCtrl` (popup), so I added the same directive to that. When I tested it, I got error which is `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [compareTo, compareTo] asking for new/isolated scope on:`. The code is below.

```
angular.module('listEmployee')
    .controller('listEmployeeCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$document', funcListEmployeeCtrl   ])
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', funcModalInstanceCtrl)
    .directive("compareTo", ['$timeout', funcCompareTo]);
```

After that I tried removing the `compareTo` directive from `listEmployeeController.js` and the error is gone. It is, then, working as expected (the `compareTo` directive can be used in `listEmployeeView.html`'s modal) even though it is not registered to its controller.

My **funcCompareTo** is as below.

```
function funcCompareTo($timeout) {
    return {
        require: "?ngModel",
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            $timeout(function(){

                if (!ngModel) {
                    console.log("can't get ngModel.");
                    return;
                }
                ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
                    console.log(modelValue+"; "+scope.otherModelValue);
                    if (modelValue == '') return true;
                    return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
                };

                scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
                    ngModel.$validate();
                });

            }, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

As I only registered the directive in `registerEmployeeCtrl`, how come that directive is existed in `ModalInstanceCtrl`?

Comment: you seem to be confusing modules with controllers.  you don't register directives with specific controllers, you register them once to a module, and they are usable anywhere that module is injected into the app.

Comment: @Claies that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation, appreciate it!